# Syncing Local Database with SQL Server on Ionic

Tags: sql-server, node.js, ionic-framework

I currently have an SQL Server database running on a VM. I also have a REST API made with NodeJS and ExpressJS that is listening for requests connected to this database for the backend.

On the frontend, I would like my Ionic App to have a local database so that users can still view and use the app when there is no internet connection. There are alot of pictures(paths to pictures) on this database. The database is about 3 GB. What is the best way I can implement so that my App can use a local database that will sync with the SQL Server and be able to view the pictures when there is a data connection?

I have looked at PouchDB, however it is a NoSQL local database. Is there anything similar for SQL Server I can use for my front end?

Comment: Take a look at [sqlite plugin](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/)

Comment: I have looked at it, but how would this sync with the SQL Server?

Comment: I think, that you have to implement the sync process by your own...